# default value for required arguments of custom activities in Workflow Foundation

Tags: c#, arguments, workflow-foundation-4, default-value, workflow-activity

In writing Custom Activities for a re-hosted Workflow Designer, it gives me an error that there is a value required for the Required Argument if I don't have one, so I either use a null as seen below or "ALL". It does not accept null or "ALL" or anything else for a default argument. Please note that my required argument is of type string.

```
[RequiredArgument]
[DefaultValue(null)]
[Description(@"The status of the job to perform")]
public InArgument<string> JobStatus { get; set; }

[RequiredArgument]
[DefaultValue("All")]
[Description(@"The status of the job to perform")]
public InArgument<string> JobStatus { get; set; }
```

Error Message when Running the Workflow :

> Workflow Console: Starting Workflow...
>
> Could not start workflow.
>
> Message: Failed to start workflow DynamicActivity.
>
> Exception message: The following errors were encountered while processing the workflow tree:
>   'DynamicActivity': The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error:   Value for a required activity argument 'JobStatus' was not supplied.
>
> Stack trace:    at System.Activities.Validation.ActivityValidationServices.ThrowIfViolationsExist(IList`1 validationErrors)
>      at System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstance.ValidateWorkflow(WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensionManager)
>      at System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstance.RegisterExtensionManager(WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensionManager)
>      at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.EnsureInitialized()
>      at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Enqueue(InstanceOperation operation, Boolean push)
>      at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.WaitForTurn(InstanceOperation operation, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.InternalRun(TimeSpan timeout, Boolean isUserRun)
>      at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Run()

Thanks for your help

Comment: So you're saying that if you don't use `DefaultValue` you're getting a compile error?

Comment: No I don't get a compile error. When I run the program the workflow wont run. I will post the error message in a minute.

Comment: Why are you executing a workflow without validating it first? And isn't the workflow designer warning you that a value is required for those InArguments?

Comment: I did not write the original code, I have to check to see if there is a way to invoke a validate first or could it be that validate is called.  By the way, when running the workflow that is exactly the error I get.  Required Argument value missing (paraphrasing)

Comment: Check [ActivityValidationServices.Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd779572(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither workflow runtime nor workflow designer will look into `DefaultValueAttribute`. Searching attributes requires reflection which might be costly on performance. Moreover that's not the purpose of the attribute.

Anyway, you can either initialize the variable with a default value. On constructor, for example:

```
public class MyCodeActivity : CodeActivity
{
    public MyCodeActivity()
    {
        JobStatus = "All";
    }
}
```

or force a value through accessor. Something like this:

```
private InArgument<string> text = "All";

[RequiredArgument]
public InArgument<string> Text
{
    get { return text ?? "All"; }
    set { text = value; }
}
```

These are different approaches, use the one that fits into the behavior you want. In both cases the value can always be modified through XAML so a small check on runtime might be good:

```
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
    string text = context.GetValue(this.Text);
    if (text == null) 
    {
        text = "All";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Comment: Another way to do this is to implement `IActivityTemplateFactory`, as in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3311256/1228).

Comment: Absolutely. Unfortunately, and this is obviously a personal opinion, `IActivityTemplateFactory` is evil and tends to hide most of the problems instead of solving them. In addition to being able to turn the design experience a complete nightmare.

Comment: Thank you.  So what is the purpose of the DefaultValue?

Comment: "*Moreover that's not the purpose of the attribute*". I might have exaggerated saying it this way. In reality `DefaultValueAttribute` can be used for whatever the developer wants. Its just metadata, which you can be retrieve and use whenever (and wherever) you want. The most usual use cases are those related with (de)serialization where metadata is used in case of value omission. In reality this attribute is used by most Visual Studio designers (WPF, WinForms, etc.). Unfortunately the WF designer isn't using it. [Related info.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311339)

Comment: @Jota : can you take a look at my other two question on Workflow errors in a re-hosted workflow designer please?  Thanks.